# Setting font-weight on Canvas text

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to write text over an image using the Canvas Element.

I've set the font-weight to 900, but on mobile it doesn't show up.

On desktop it's fine and even testing it within responsive mode it looks fine, but when I make it live, the heavier font-weight doesn't come through on my phone.

I tried the code snippet in the comments of [Debug JS modifying some specific canvas element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789703/debug-js-modifying-some-specific-canvas-element) to debug it and I found that for some reason the `ctx.font` was only storing the font size and font name, but not the font weight.

I added the word `bold` and it would store that, but not `bolder` or a number value.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

I've included a code snippet and a screenshot from my debugging that shows how it's storing the font value.

[image: Screenshot]

```
function main() {
  // Put template on canvas
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, size, size);

  ctx.font = "bold 110px 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.fillText(number, 325, 290);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, your font is not installed on a phone. Try let f = new FontFace('test', 'url(x)');

f.load().then(function() {
  // Ready to use the font in a canvas context
});

Answer (score 5):

Chrome and Safari require that the *font-style* is also set in order to use a numerical value for *font-weight*:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
// add 'normal' font-style
ctx.font = "normal 900 24px Unknown, sans-serif";
ctx.fillText( "bold", 50, 50 );

ctx.font = "24px Unknown, sans-serif";
ctx.fillText( "normal", 150, 50 );
```

```css
canvas { background: white }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.  I used ctx.font = "normal 900 110px 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif"; but it's still not coming through at the heavier font-weight on mobile and in the debugger it's still only showing "110px 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif"  It's a Google Font, so maybe I'll play around with a non-google font to see if that's part of the issue or not.

Comment: This answer was the key for me; compose a font name: `${style} ${weight} ${size}px ${family}`  where 'weight' is numeric. anything else reverts to the default style: for ex (10px sans-serif);   I'm using createjs/easeljs to put Text onto a Canvas/Stage. [note: the easeljs Text documentation says: [any CSS font string, for example "30px Arial bold"] but that example does NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried this on Chrome (109.0.5414.87), numbered font-weights are converted to keywords. 100 to 600 are converted to "normal" and disappeared, and 700 - 900 are converted to "bold".

```js
var context = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
context.font = "100 16px Arial" 
console.log(context.font) // prints "16px Arial"


context.font = "700 16px Arial" 
console.log(context.font) // prints "bold 16px Arial"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've set the font-weight to 900, but on mobile it doesn't show up.
>
> On desktop it's fine and even testing it within responsive mode it
> looks fine

Can you check that link? I'm not sure is it related your problem but It can help: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_picture.asp