# How to build a specific version of Chromium?

Tags: git, chromium, ninja, gclient

I want to build the latest stable version of Chromium (`62.0.3202.84` at the time of writing, see [OmahaProxy](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/)).

The [build instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md) work just fine for the current development version.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481803/how-to-get-code-of-specified-tag-version-of-chromium-from-git/26462483#26462483), the [Brave wiki](https://github.com/brave/browser-android-tabs/wiki/Get-stable-chromium) and some other sources, the instructions to fetch and build a specific version seem to be pretty clear :

```sh
git fetch origin 62.0.3202.84
git checkout -b my_stable_branch FETCH_HEAD
# hooks and dependencies if needed, commits, compilation...
```

However, this does **not** seem to work for me. When I create a branch for `FETCH_HEAD`, a quick `git log` shows that I have the latest commits from `master`.

What am I misunderstanding ?

**EDIT**:

If I do [the steps from Asesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185985/how-to-build-a-specific-version-of-chromium#answer-47219175) from `master`, it runs “successfully” but I still end up building `master` instead of what I want.

If I first create a branch from a specific tag (as specified in [the Chromium documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches)), like `62.0.3202.84`, or even if I just check it out without branching, `gclient sync --with_branch_heads` fails giving me the following error :

```
Error: Command 'git checkout --quiet 6e4c388c0117fe408b66fbede91081fb1018c5fe' returned non-zero exit status 128 in /path/to/chromium/src/media/cdm/api
fatal: reference is not a tree: 6e4c388c0117fe408b66fbede91081fb1018c5fe
```

Comment: I peeked into the code of `gclient`; the error I get is probably tied to that specific version (i.e. 3202) of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I successfully compiled version 3239, so I understand the problem was a bad reference in 3202's `DEPS` file. <sub>(which is quite weird...)</sub>

Hence the following steps are actually correct:

```
git checkout -b your_branch xx.x.xxxx.xx
gclient sync
```

**EDIT 2018-07-02:** According to [this page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches), starting from version 3420, it should be possible to correctly sync dependencies.